# Do surreal numbers contain all other number systems?

Tags: surreal-numbers

I know that some operations are defined for surreal numbers like addition or multiplication.

Are all operations for all "number systems" defined for surreal numbers in a way that they give same result as respective operations defined for those "number systems"?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Can't you define "closeness" and absolute value in two different ways on surreal numbers? Like "real closeness" and "p-adic closeness" and have surreal numbers still cover both real and p-addic systems? Would you be so kind to upvote my question?

Comment: "$p$-adic closeness" is defined on rational numbers, not (sur)real numbers

Comment: There isn't a copy of the complex numbers in the surreals.

Comment: that's a good point, @MarkS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, surreal numbers do not contain all other number systems.  They contain real numbers, which are a completion of rational numbers using the ordinary absolute value as a metric, but not [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), which are a completion of rational numbers using the $p$-adic metric, where numbers are smaller if they are divisible by a higher power of $p$.